# Algorithm : how to split list data into fixed size sub-lists without having separate numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, sublist

I have an algorithmic question for you. No need for an application context, I'll give you a direct example.

Here is a possible input: input = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ].
Let's assume a batch size of 5.
The idea here is to output lists of maximum size 5 without having separate number, in short: 2 identical numbers cannot be in separate sub-lists.
Example output: [ [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4, 4] ]

Assumptions: Numbers always sorted, batch_size always larger than possible number of numbers

Do you have a more elegant solution than the one I just found?

```py
i = 0
batch_size = 5
res = []
while i < len(input):
    # Retrieve the data list according to the batch size
    data = input[i: i + size]
    # Increment the index
    i += size
    # See what's the next output looks like
    future_data = input[i: i + size]
    if future_data and future_data[0] == data[-1]:
        # So we count how many times this number appears in our current list 
        # and subtract that from our index
        cp = data.count(data[-1])
        i -= cp
        # Then remove from the current list all occurrence of that number
        data = data[:-cp]
    res.append(data)
```

**Edit: according to @juanpa.arrivillaga's answer:**

Thank you all for your reactivity and your answers.

I continue on episode 2, I gave you here my simplified problem and I thought your solution would be sufficient, despite your response, I do not see how to adapt the solution of @juanpa.arrivillaga to my data format, in fact the input would look more like :

```py
input = { 
    'data_1' : { 
        'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 
        'char': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'] 
    }
}
```

!the size of the lists in value of 'id' and 'char' are necessarily equal!

the output must look like:

```py
[ 
    [1, 'A', 1, 'B', 1, 'C'], 
    [2, 'D', 2, 'E', 2, 'F', 2, 'G'], 
    [3, 'H', 3, 'I', 4, 'J', 4, 'K', 4, 'L'] 
]
```

I am aware that the data structure is not optimal, unfortunately I don't have the hand on it and is therefore unchangeable...

Still the same constrains as before (batch size is working only on the id, am I clear enough ?)

Comment: why 3&4 are grouped together?

Comment: this question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I will solve it. But some questions. Should there always exist a list in the output having size 5? And lengths of output list are always consecutive?

Comment: As I can see in your example length of the first list is 3, second is 4, and the third is 5.

Comment: It would be clear for me if you send me some more example

Comment: Say you have `[1,1,2,2,3,3,3]`, what answer do you want to get? `[[1,1],[2,2,3,3,3]]` or `[[1,1,2,2],[3,3,3]]` and why?

Comment: So, algorithmically, I woudl avoid `cp = data.count(data[-1])` in the loop, it makes your algorithm quadratic time and I'm pretty sure you can do this in linear time. Just create a counter ahead of time with a first pass... `counts = collections.Counter(data)`

Comment: Yeah, so why shouldn't the result be: `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]`?

Comment: The output contains `[2, 2, 2, 2]` but there are only 3 `2`s in the input. Also I don't understand what "without having separate number" means.

Comment: @ j_random_hacker Maybe he misprints it. He does mean four 2's in input

Comment: Edit: @j_random_hacker yes, it's a typo, four 2's are in input

Comment: @Nk03 grouped is not the actual problem, because the final sub lists size are less or equal than 5

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh ok, really interesting thanks

Comment: OK, but it's still not clear what "without having separate number" means.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I clarify: 2 identical numbers cannot be in separate sub-lists

Comment: Thanks! It's clear now.

Comment: So the output can also be this : [[1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3], [4,4,4]]. If not then why

Comment: @RishabhSemwal No, not in my case, you have to full-fill the sublists whenever you can, because the length of [3, 3, 4, 4, 4] does not exceed the size of the batch, it's ok. In fact, you can mix different numbers in sub lists but not separate same numbers in different sub list

Comment: @JanWilamowski what's codereview.stackexchange.com ? Do you think I should post my question there ?

Comment: whats wrong with this output : [[1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3], [4,4,4]].

Comment: @RishabhSemwal the limit list size is 5. Similar numbers must be in the same sub list. As you can see, [3, 3]'s list is of length 2, so you can hypothetically add more elements into it. Luckily, we have three 4's ! Add them into [3, 3, 4, 4, 4] the list size is now 5, we cannot add more element into it. However, if we had four 4"s and one 5's the output would look like: [[1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3], [4,4,4,4, 5]]. Get it?

Comment: That means a list with length 5 must exists in output

Comment: @RishabhSemwal not necessary, but as long as you can add element into a list, you must do it

Comment: Ok I got it. We have to choose a bigger list if it can happen but not bigger than batch_size. So instead of writing [3,3] , [4,4,4] we can write it better as [3,3,4,4,4]

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do this, in a single pass:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> batch_size = 5
>>> result = [[]]
>>> input_data = [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ]
>>> for _, g in itertools.groupby(input_data):
...     current = list(g)
...     if len(result[-1]) + len(current) <= batch_size:
...         result[-1].extend(current)
...     else:
...         result.append(current)
...
>>> result
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

Let's break it down into intermediate steps to aid in understanding, first, this is what `itertools.groupby` does eagerly evaluated:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> batch_size = 5
>>> grouped = [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4 ])]
>>> grouped
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

Then, simply build up your result, which is a list of sublists. If it can fit into the current sublist, add the group to the sublist, otherwise, append a new sublist consisting of that group (which we can assume is not larger than batch_size):

```
>>> result = [[]]
>>> for group in grouped:
...     if len(result[-1]) + len(group) <= batch_size:
...         result[-1].extend(group)
...     else:
...         result.append(group[:])
...
>>> result
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

The above does two passes on the data, the first example posted does one pass.

Note, if using `itertools.groupby` feels like "cheating", you can implement something that does the trick for this case relatively easy:

```
def simple_groupby(data):
    it = iter(data)
    empty = object()
    current = next(it, empty)
    if current is empty:
        return
    prev = current
    acc = [current]
    for current in it:
        if prev == current:
            acc.append(current)
        else:
            yield acc
            acc = [current]
        prev = current
    yield acc
```

Comment: starting with an empty list in the `result` list is elegant IMO

Comment: @VPfB yeah, depending on edge-case behavior that is desired it might not be the correct way, e.g. what if you pass an empty list? Should it return an empty list? But those are all details the OP can work out

Comment: This should be the answer. I would like to suggest an improvement: instead of using `groupby`, we just need to count and store in a list or `pair(number, count)`.

Comment: @TuanChau well, it would be better to store a `dict` of counts.  But I think `groupby` would be better in any case, it is an efficient implementation of exactly what we need

Comment: There is a problem. Your ouput doesn't matches with his output

Comment: @RishabhSemwal yes, I am almost certain because the OP meant `input =  [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, ]` (ie., with four 2's) instead of what they posted

Comment: Yeah, luckily, Python's `dict` will provide sorted by insert order keys. In general language, that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your reply ! I edited my input to match my output

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Your solution is working like a charm and is much more efficient & elegant than mine, congrats :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with a recursive generator function to find possible merges that meet your criteria. This way, you can better handle more ambiguous cases where it is unclear which "sibling" group should absorb the double pairing and/or truncated results where groups have a length greater than `batch_size`:

```
from itertools import groupby
data = {'data_1': {'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], 'char': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']}}
batch_size = 5
def get_groups(d, c = [], p = []):
  if not d and not p and all((l:=len(i)) <= batch_size and i and l != 2 for i in c):
     #found valid combo
     yield c
  elif d:
     _p = (k:=(p+d[0]))[(b:=(l if (l:=len(k)) <= batch_size else -1*(l-batch_size))):]
     if l == 2 and not _p:
        #if group size is two, then we have to find possible merges for group
        yield from get_groups(d[1:], c=c, p = k)
        yield from get_groups([c[-1]+k]+d[1:], c=c[:-1], p = [])
     elif _p:
        #group size > batch_size, need to find possible siblings that can take subgroups of groups
        for i in range(batch_size):
           yield from get_groups(d[1:], c=c+[k[:i]], p = k[i:])
           if c and len(c[-1]) + i <= batch_size:
              yield from get_groups(d[1:], c=c[:-1]+[c[-1]+k[batch_size:batch_size+i]]+[k[:batch_size]], p = k[batch_size+i:])
     yield from get_groups(d[1:], c=c+[k[:b]], p = _p)
  elif p:
     yield from get_groups(d[1:], c=c+[p], p = [])

combo = next(get_groups([list(b) for _, b in groupby(data['data_1']['id'])]))
c_m = iter(data['data_1']['char'])
result = [[i for j in [(x, next(c_m)) for x in y] for i in j] for y in combo]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'A', 1, 'B', 1, 'C'], [2, 'D', 2, 'E', 2, 'F', 2, 'G'], [3, 'H', 3, 'I', 4, 'J', 4, 'K', 4, 'L']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any library(module), then this solution is for you.

```py
batch_size = 5
id = list(map(int, input("Enter multiple ids in one line with space between them: ").split()))
char = list(map(str, input("Enter multiple char in one line with space between them: ").split()))
id_char_input = {char[i]: id[i] for i in range(len(id))}
id_unique = list(set([value for key, value in id_char_input.items()]))
group_input = [[] for _ in range(len(id_unique))]
output = []
j = 0

for key, value in id_char_input.items():
    group_input[id_unique.index(value)].append(value)
    group_input[id_unique.index(value)].append(key)

while j < len(group_input):
    if j != len(group_input) - 1:
        if len(group_input[j] + group_input[j + 1]) <= 2*batch_size:
            output.append(group_input[j] + group_input[j + 1])
            j += 2
        else:
            if group_input[j] not in output:
                output.append(group_input[j])
            j += 1
    else:
        output.append(group_input[j])
        break

print(output)
```

```
Output:
Enter multiple ids in one line with space between them: 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4
Enter multiple char in one line with space between them: A B C D E F G H I J K L
[[1, 'A', 1, 'B', 1, 'C'], [2, 'D', 2, 'E', 2, 'F', 2, 'G'], [3, 'H', 3, 'I', 4, 'J', 4, 'K', 4, 'L']]
```

EDIT: Now you can take values of id and char from the input.

Comment: Haha nice @Rishabh Semwal, thank you for spending time on this problem. However you have changed the input format, that's illegal ;) In my case, I don't know in advance how much entries I'll have in my input : ex { "data_1": {"col1": [], "col2": [], "col3": [], "col4": [], .....} }. The only thing I know for sure is that all the lists are the same length.

Comment: Do you also want char to be stored from input?

Comment: I edited the answer as you said. Check it.

Comment: @MarwanLkd Does this answer helped you. If not then tell me?